# Porting ASP.NET application to Mono/Apache under Linux

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linux, mono

I've got a relatively small ASP.NET project that was written using C# 4.0.

I was wondering if anybody had managed to port such a project over to running under a webserver on Linux, the latest information I can find appears to only have support for ASP.Net 2.0 - [Configuring and running Mono ASP.NET 3.5 (AJAX.NET) on Linux computers](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET)

The project uses LINQ-to-SQL for the entire data access layer, and I know Mono itself support LINQ, so I thought it stands to reason that it should work.

I just want to know if it's a complete waste of time or not before starting.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running your assemblies under Apache/Mono? The best thing you can do is just try and see what breaks or use the Mono Migration analyzer http://mono-framework.com/MoMA.

Comment: There is a good chance it will work quite well. Give it a try as above

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I run an ASP.NET 4.0 application on Suse Linux using mono. My experience with mono is that it just works. My app is ~ 15.000 LOC and uses third party components like mongo-csharp-driver, lucene.net, elmah, munq, and sphorium.webdavserver.

I've had almost no compatibility problems during development - and the ones I had where easily worked out (for example sphorium accesses the registry; this obviously works different on Linux/Mono). I've even started developing with Visual Studio instaed of MonoDevelop and without the Mono plugin, because Visual Studio is a better IDE, and it just works when I compile my web app on linux and deploy it on Apache (even though I develop with .NET on Windows).

[I've written a short blogpost on getting started with the setup](http://retkomma.wordpress.com/2011/12/23/setup-mono-mod_mono-and-apache-an-introduction-do-windows-developers/)

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely not a waste of time. The company I work for converted our VB.Net application to C# so that it can run under mono. This application has over 200k lines of code. We now are running with Ubuntu/Apache/Mono/Postgresql on Amazon ec2.

The only concern I would have is with your database. If it is MS SQL then you will need to look at migrating to MySQL or Postgresql. Again we did this with 300+ tables and 900 stored procedures. It is definately something worthwhile in the long run.

I think that the best way to get started would be to setup a local environment running something like Ubuntu. You can get the near latest versions of mono from the repositories at http://badgerports.org/ or if you prefer you can the latest versions as build scripts which are maintained [here](http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2011/08/install-mono-2-10-3-on-ubuntu-using-bash-script/). Install monodevelop and build your code on linux with mono. From experience the mono with C# is a pretty much a complete implementation of the .net framework. I would be surprised if there was something in your application that is yet to be implemented in mono.

I have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762926/setting-up-modmono-with-apache2/8554095#8554095) showing an easy configuration for your application under apache. I use this configuration for mono applications running on Ubuntu.

Comment: "The only concern I would have is with your database." - our database server is MS SQL, but it's a different machine than the one I want to run this project on. Shouldn't I be able to use the ASP.NET project under Apache while having it connect using the sql data provider for MSSQL to our database on our db server?

Comment: Yes you will be able to do this.

Comment: @lanks, could I ask just a slightly off-topic question what ORM (if any) did you use? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Macias. We did not use an ORM. I have however done another project with servicestack using postgresql. Servicestack uses OrmLite https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite. Another ORM that I have not used but have heard good things about is Dapper https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net. These are both very lightweight ORM's.